# No firebase, como ler o valor do metadado "Criado em" dos usuários?

Tags: android, firebase

Pretendo obter a data de criação do cadastro do usuário no aplicativo, para computar um período de trial. Pensei em criar uma cloud function pra alimentar uma variável com este valor, o que seria perfeito para novos casos, mas não adiantaria nada para os quase 270 usuários em produção. Porém, vi que no painel já existe tal data e gostaria de obter este dado. Como consigo acessar este dado?

[image: Print do console]

Answer (score 1):

Você pode capturar esses dados utilizando o CLI do firebase com o comando:

```
firebase auth:export account_file --format=file_format
```

onde account_file é o nome do arquivo onde os dados serão salvos e file_format o tipo de arquivo, podendo ser CSV ou JSON. Os resultados para o JSON são mais ou menos assim:

```
  {"users": [...
  {"localId": "key",
  "email": "email@email.com",
  "emailVerified": false,
  "passwordHash": "hash==",
  "salt": "salt==",
  "lastSignedInAt": "1504893158000",
  "createdAt": "1504558948000",
  "providerUserInfo": []
  }
  ...]}
```

[Firebase auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli/auth)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o Firebase Admin SDK para poder pegar a data. Mas não é possível utilizá-lo no android. Acredito que para os novos usuários você faz com metadata, e cria um programa em java simples utilizando o SDK e alimenta esta base de dados.

Só comentando, não é possível utilizar no Android por dois motivos:

1. Se você adicionar um SDK desse em um aplicativo para o publico geral, você vai dar poder para eles administrar sua infra.
2. Os nomes de pacotes para ambas as plataformas são iguais, e você teria conflitos no android.

O Admin SDK também tem uma versão para node.js, então acho que da pra usar nos cloud functions também (me corrijam se estiver errado)

Comment: Na verdade apenas o Firebase Admin SDK para plataforma NodeJS oferece o suporte ao gerenciamento de usuários.  
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup?hl=pt-br